# Calling a method on an object that's created by another method?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Bit stuck on a bit of my Java code. I have adjusted the code below to give a trivial example, the answers will still be applicable. Basically,

I have three class files: GUI, main, pipe1.

My GUI accepts some values for variables: `length` and `height`.
It then calls `main.makePipe` which is a static method containing an if statement which then creates a new `pipe1` called `createdPipe`. Sample:

```
  public static void makePipe(double length, double width){
    if(length > 0 && length < 4){
        pipe createdPipe = new pipe1(length, height);
```

Now my new `createpipe` object has a method called `basicCost` which makes returns the cost of the pipe:

```
protected void calculateCost(){
   double basicCost = height * length + 300;
   return basicCost;
   }
```

I'm stuck on how to get this returned value all the way back to the GUI class?
If I run (in my GUI class):

```
createdpipe.calculateCost();
```

it says cannot find symbol. Rightly so.
If I create a method in `main` and put:

```
public double finalCost(){
pipeCost = createdPipe.calculateCost();
return pipeCost;
}
```

and try to call it from my GUI (`main.finalCost`) I get an: non static method cannot be reference from a static context.

I understand why, but can anyone tell me how I can make this object known to the GUI class or a way I can calculate data on the pipe1 class and return the data to the GUI class to be used?

Answer (score 1):

the createdPipe is a local variable, so you need to change the scope of this variable.

you should declare a static variable reference to the createdPipe Object in main, like this:

```
private static pipe1 createdPipe;
```

change the makePipe method, so it will create createdPipe:

```
public static void makePipe(double length, double width){
    if(length > 0 && length < 4){
        createdPipe = new pipe1(length, height);
```

then you should declare the finalCost as static method:

```
public static double finalCost()
```

because createdPipe can be null, you should check if createdPipe is null in finalCost method.

Comment: Or use `makePipe` as a type of factory method that returns new instances of `pipe1`, but it's still a valid concept - But I'd prefer not to over use `static`, seen as the OP hasn't ;)

Comment: Thank for you response, unfortunately I cannot make the calculateCost a static method because it causes the other variables used in the method cause the non static variable error.. any other suggestions?

Comment: @user3053434 , sorry, should declare the finalCost as static method, `public static double finalCost()`